# How do I compare armour pieces for my companion?

Tags: fallout-4

I know that when you're examining an armour piece in your inventory, its protection values relative to your currently equipped piece are displayed with +/- next to the value depending on how better/worse it is.

Is it possible to display the same comparison when equipping your companion? When I am going through their inventory to decide what they should wear, I'm getting the comparison to *my* gear, not theirs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to view companion armor in the same way you view your own.

However, armor has relativley the same effect on your companion, as it does on your player character.

A viable option would be to take the original armor from your companion, equip it, and compare other armor in relation to your player character.

Also note that fallout uses a base assumption when displaying armor as an upgrade. Depending on your playstyle, a percieved "upgrade" may not necessarily be an upgrade, as base values are compared, but not secondary effects.

Comment: Aside from undergarments, you can rename armor. I put *s at the start of my armor and (Cait) at the start of my companion's armor (when it's Cait). Then if I feel like upgrading my companion's armor I just take it, put it on, and look through my stockpile til I find better (or potentially better) armor. Then when I mod it I rename it so I can easily find it again if I accidentally TAKE ALL from my companion.

Comment: @aslum That's a useful feature, but (at least on XB1) there's a very restrictive character limit. One which the game itself appears able to violate very regularly, but you may not. So, you could end up gathering/making equipment that you can't simply rename in the way you suggest.

Comment: @Iszi Yeah, the PC has the same limit so usually my armor ends up being either **(Nick) Left Arm** or **(Hancock) R Leg**. W/out a Keyboard I'd probably do something like **[H] R Leg**

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it is possible. You'll have to compare each piece separately or use yourself to get the highest value.

I normally take the best set and put it into a container and make the next best set. After which I give it to my companion.

Answer (score 0):

Since the shown comparison is with your armor, the only way to get that exact same display would be to put your companion's armor on yourself, and then give it back once done comparing.

That seems like a bit of a hassle to me.

Here's what I do:

1. Trade with my companion.
2. Put the armor that I'm considering having them wear in their inventory,
   along with the stuff they already have equipped.
3. Page over to the Apparel page.
4. Press the sort button (left stick on the XBox) to sort by damage
   (DMG). This will sort in descending order by the sum of the armor's
   resistances. This includes not only physical and energy resistance,
   but others as well such as radiation resistance.

Now, it should be pretty easy to get an idea of how the prospective armor compares to the current armor by where it falls in the sort list, and they're all right next to each other for visual inspection and comparison.

Comment: *Super* curious what that downvote is for, if anybody has any clue.